remove paragraphs in phpWord table
There is a space in the table. I couldnt remove it. It's not just a space, tab, align or 4space. this image is the wrong one, it should be like this this image is the true one
        $information = new Table(array(
            'borderSize' => 6,
            'borderColor' => '999999',
            'width' => 12000,
        ));

        $myFontStyle = array('bold' => true, 'align' => 'center', 'size' => 11, 'name' => 'Times New Roman');
        $cellRowSpan = array('vMerge' => 'restart');


        $information->addRow();
        $information->addCell(500, $cellRowSpan)->addText('№', $myFontStyle);
//        $information->addCell(1500, $cellRowSpan)->addText('1 кв.м учун қиймати сумда', $myFontStyle);
        $information->addCell(2200, $cellRowSpan)->addText(trans('contract.information.total'), $myFontStyle);
        $information->addCell(1900, $cellRowSpan)->addText(trans('contract.information.initial'), $myFontStyle);
        $information->addCell(2100, $cellRowSpan)->addText(trans('contract.information.total_nds'), $myFontStyle);
        $information->addCell(2200, $cellRowSpan)->addText(trans('contract.information.installment_month'), $myFontStyle);
        $information->addCell(1900, $cellRowSpan)->addText(trans('contract.information.debt_price'), $myFontStyle);



I know, I 've already answered. Anyway ... what have you tried so far? How did you try to remove the unwanted content? The shown code tells us nothing about what you 've tried so far.

First remove all tabs from the string you want to insert in the table cell
$output = preg_replace("/\t+/", " ", $input);

After that remove all repeated whitspaces from the string you want to insert in the table cell.
$output = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $input);

